# Python получить определенные цифры которые находятся между другими словами

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Вопрос заключается в том что написан парсер который достаёт ссылки пример:
'/asdas131/2346877/123asdasd'
Мне нужно убрать все слева и справа от цифр.
Каким образом я могу это реализовать.
Должно получиться '2346877'

Comment: Регулярными выражениями `\d+` - цифры, `\D+` - не цифры

Comment: @CrazyElf, Допустим справа от цифр есть другие цифры то что в этом данные цифры тоже будут выделяться*.
\w* нашел решение и через массив. Но данный способ мне тоже не нравиться.

Comment: Приведите понятный пример: есть то-то, хочу на выходе получить то-то. Если будет несколько блоков цифр - хочу получить такой-то результат на выходе. А так это вы меняете условия на ходу и спрашиваете, что выдаст решение, предложенное на предыдущую версию ваших данных. Зачем? Поставьте понятно задачу - вам предложат решение под неё.

Comment: @CrazyElf Согласен моя ошибка, исправил

Comment: "убрать все слева и справа от цифр" - и всё-равно непонятно, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Покажите, какую строку или список строк или что вы хотите получить на выходе. Сейчас непонятно - что делать со слешами и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = '/asdas131/2346877/123asdasd'
```

можно используя метод split(), указав в параметрах, в качестве разделителя '/'

```
r = t.split('/')
```

разделит строку на части, вернет список строк:
['', 'asdas131', '2346877', '123asdasd']

получаем нужную строку по индексу:

```
print(r[2])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Длинна ссылки статическая? Если да, то можно срезом.
Если нет то вот:

```
import string

a = string.ascii_letters + ""  # в кавычки можешь дописать еще символы которые хочешь убрать
s = '/asdas131/2346877/123asdasd'
sn = ""

for i in s:
    if a.find(i) == -1:
        sn += i
print(sn)
```